# Json SelectListItem add item to top of list

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am returning the following Json within an ActionResult:

```
return Json(_lookUp.GetMgmtByIDs(_mgmtService.GetMgmt(D).ToList(), selectedIDs.ToList())
                            .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.SName, Value = x.SID.ToString() }) 
                            .OrderBy(y => y.Text), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

I need to add the an item to the top of the list: "Please Select" with a value of 0. I am not sure how to do this.

I know we can do the following but does not work in this case:

```
.Insert(0, "Please Select");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say that something like this will probably work:

```
new[]{ new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select", Value = "0" } }.Concat(

  _lookUp.GetMgmtByIDs(_mgmtService.GetMgmt(D).ToList(), selectedIDs.ToList())
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.SName, Value = x.SID.ToString() })
    .OrderBy(y => y.Text)

)
```

though it might cause you some translation issue in the future

> I know we can do the following but does not work in this case:

That'll work if you materialize to a List first:

```
var list = _lookUp.GetMgmtByIDs(_mgmtService.GetMgmt(D).ToList(), selectedIDs.ToList())
    .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.SName, Value = x.SID.ToString() })
    .OrderBy(y => y.Text)
    .ToList();

list.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "Please Select", Value = "0" });
```

and then return the `list`